# Are drivers needed after an ubuntu install

Tags: drivers

i wanted to install ubuntu 14.04 on my 7 years old laptop. I have a computer maintenance class in school where we installed Windows XP and we had to search for drivers. It is tiring and iI still haven't found all of them. My question was that do i need to search for drivers after installing ubuntu too or is this driver thing just for windows.

I am new to this stuff so would appreciate any help.d

Comment: Are you asking about installing drivers in Ubuntu or Windows?

Comment: For a seven year old laptop, I would guess most things would work as expected. Maybe you can have issues with wireless but we wouldn't really know that until you try it out. But I would recommend you try out Lubuntu or Xubuntu since they are lighter.

Comment: I wanted to install drivers on linux.

Answer (score 1):

Whether you need to install drivers or not, depends on the specific hardware components used in the machine. This is the same both on Ubuntu and Windows.

However, Ubuntu uses the concept of **Generic Drivers**, drivers which are made to fit a large range of hardware components. E.g. the open-source nVidia driver installed by default, *noveau*, supports most of nVidia's graphics cards. However, you may experience a lack of support for certain features of some devices, like the nVidia Optimus technology. If you want to use this, you have to install a specific driver, as an example *nvidia-prime*, a nVidia-proprietary driver for Optimus support on Linux.

I've also seen Windows use this concept, but never to the extent Ubuntu does. As far as my experience goes, the drivers preinstalled on Ubuntu cover up most of the not too new devices out there, save for a few exceptions.

As an example, I once had a Toshiba laptop which I wiped and reinstalled Windows 7. The graphics worked, but only 4:3 on a 16:9 screen. But there it stopped - nearly no device in this laptop had its driver preinstalled in Windows 7, not even a Ethernet driver, so I couldn't download them.
When I installed Ubuntu, everything worked out of the box. However, the ethernet was a bit slow, so I installed a specific driver from the manufacturer of the Ethernet card and had better surf speed after.

---

To see, whether you will actually have to install additional drivers, you can boot Ubuntu directly from a DVD or USB stick. The system will run, as if it was installed on the computer (except it will be a bit slower when run from USB or DVD). You can play with everything and see what works and what doesn't. If something doesn't work (well) you can be almost sure that somewhere out there either some company or some free devs created a working driver for the device.

Known proprietary drivers can be installed using the *Software & Updates* utility, in the tab *Additional Drivers*. Many open source drivers can be installed from the official repositories. And if you don't find them there, you may stumble over a PPA, DEB/DKMS package, to install or even source code to compile the driver directly on your machine.

---

To actually find out the name of devices you need or want a driver for (if you didn't find it in *Additional Drivers*), use the commands `sudo lshw` and `lspci`.

`lshw` creates a detailed report, including name and vendor, if detected, on basically any hardware in the computer. If you install the package `lshw-gtk`, all this information will become much more readable in a GUI. If there is no driver at all installed for the device you're searching for, you'll most likely find the tag `UNCLAIMED`. So this is a good place to start.

`lspci` lists all devices connected to a PCI bus. This includes Network Controllers, Graphics Cards, Audio and Video devices (Screen, Speaker), USB Controllers, and so on... Most of them are listed with a name, however mostly a generic one.

Comment: How can i see the name or model number of my hardware to download the correct drivers as I can't open my laptop.

Comment: Added it to my answer